# How to open worklight app settings on android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am launched Worklight app on the android device. I have included Worklight Settings on **applications-descriptor.html** for Android platform.

I haven't found nothing on the Android **Settings**.

How I can open Worklight Settings of the app to change something, like a Worklight Server URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you will mention your Android OS version as well as the used Android API Level in your Android project.

This is especially important because starting API Level 11 the Options Menu may not be visible due to deprecation by Google, and in this case you will not see the options button making it impossible to reach the button that opens the Worklight Settings page in Android.

This log is printed in LogCat as well:

> Note that if your application
>   targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might
>   have no effect, depending on the device.

The Options Menu API was replaced by the Action Bar in Andriod.
Worklight does not support that Action Bar at this time.

There is no alternative other than lowering the used API Level, which will also not help with some OS versions.

See these questions for more information:

- [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Questions about "Worklight Settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860648/ibm-worklight-6-1-questions-about-worklight-settings)
- [Worklight optionsMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704539/worklight-optionsmenu)